# pull azure function to locally and install npm

Tags: azure, visual-studio-code, azure-functions

I have craeted a new serverless function from the azure portal.

Now I would install a library with npm.

I can access to function using the Azure VS Code extension.

The problem is that I can't run `npm install` because the function is not in local repository.

How can I pull the azure function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pull/clone just for a specific function from Function App is not possible. All functions in a Function App are deployed as a single project. So you will have to download the site content from the Overview section of Function App, after which you can open it in VS Code.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can also create, run and publish Azure function locally in VS CODE using some azure extension
Like Azure function, azurite, azure account, azure storage
You also need Microsoft azure storage explorer for testing Azure Queue Messages.